# Type of vptr(Virtual Pointer) in C++

Tags: c++

Recently, I was exploring the vPtr and vtable in C++. There are many good articles on it and most of them have explained it in a very nice way.But, Unfortunately, I could not find the answer to my Question.
**I like to know what is the return type of the vPtr.** 
Thanks in advance

Comment: That question doesn't make any sense. First of all, what do *you* mean when you say "vptr"? And what do you mean about it having a return type? A pointer doesn't have a return type, only functions do. Please elaborate!

Comment: read here https://www.quora.com/What-are-vTable-and-VPTR-in-C++

Comment: look at Stephan Lechner answer below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably confused by the word "pointer" in "Virtual Pointer", as this virtual pointer is not a pointer defined by the C++ language itself (like a `char *` or a `void *` is). It is rather an internal construct used by the compiler to solve member function overriding, and this construct is not exposed to the programmer. Hence, there is no "type" like `char` or `void` for this construct, and actually vTables are not even part of the C++ language.

Comment: Thanks for such a nice explanation.But when read some articles, I learned that it holds the address of a virtual function in the Vtable. isn't it pointer is the one which holds the address of another object.Please help me to explain

Comment: This "pointer" is not available to the user. It is an internal structure used by the compiler.